# File's Owner 'view' outlet not showing

Tags: xcode, ios7, swift, xcode6

I created a project in Xcode 6 beta 2, which initial had a storyboard. I wanted to work with separated xibs so I removed storyboard and line related to storyboard from Info.plist and added several xibs. Now the problem is that I can't connect file's owner 'view' outlet (because it's not visible) to view from xib. First thought was that I misspelled name of the file's owner custom class name (from Identity Inspector), but I didn't. Also file's owner class is a UIViewController child. I don't know that the problem can be. Did some faced this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probable that you need to close Xcode, clean the project and try again. I created a new project without storyboards and I did the following:

1) I created the nib file.

2) I created the UIViewController class.

3) I opened the nib and selected the File's owner tab. Then I wrote the name of the custom UIViewController class.

4) Without selecting the file's owner tab on the Placeholders left bar (**make sure of this**) go to Connections inspector tab and you should see the view outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Simply cleaning, quitting Xcode and re-opening fixed it for me.